# Google Charts saying data unavailable

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3, google-visualization

I am trying to pull data from my database using the comprehension query syntax and then pass it as a Json object so the Google charts can display the data but it says data is unavailable.  My query syntax looks good, I even tried it in Mysql workbench and it returned the results I wanted. however, it is not returning the results I want in my C# MVC project. Maybe I am not returning the data object correctly. It works with the dummy data but not with the data from the database.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetChartData()
    {
        //var siteData = new[] { new { time = 2345, tdate = "2012, 3, 1" },
        //                       new { time = 4568, tdate = "2012, 3, 2" },
        //                       new { time = 1237, tdate = "2012, 3, 3" },
        //                       new { time = 9874, tdate = "2012, 3, 4" },
        //};

        var test = from p in _db.page_loads
                    join f in _db.sites
                    on p.site_id equals f.id
                    where f.thirdParty_id == siteId //(siteId is private int declared in my class above
                    select new { time = p.time, created_at = p.created_at };


        return Json(test);           
    }
```

and this is what my script looks like in the views section

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['annotatedtimeline'] });

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        $.post('/metrics/GetChartData', {},
        function (data) {
            var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            tdata.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
            tdata.addColumn('number', 'Times');

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                    var date = new Date(parseInt(data[i].created_at.substr(6)));
                                    var load_time = data[i].time;
                                    tdata.addRow([date, load_time]);
            }

            var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(tdata, { displayAnnotations: true });

        });

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried looking into `date` and `load_time` variables? Do they have data in them every time you loop?

Comment: yeah that was my problem. My query was returning an empty result because it was getting the 'siteId' that does not even exist. Thanks